# What kind of distribution in this chart?

Tags: statistics, functions, random-variables, inverse

Could you tell me what kind of distribution is this?

[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZi1M.jpg)

This is the data:

```
0.028047984
0.280480733
0.804808224
0.048083135
0.480832245
0.808323349
0.083234385
0.83234474
0.323448299
0.23448388
0.344839694
0.448397836
0.483979252
0.839793415
0.397935044
0.979351338
0.793514274
0.935143638
0.351437274
0.514373633
0.143737223
0.43737312
0.373732097
0.737321866
0.373219557
0.732196462
0.321965514
0.21965603
0.196561193
0.965612823
0.65612912
0.561292093
0.612921824
0.129219138
0.292192273
0.921923623
0.219237128
0.192372178
0.923722671
0.237227602
0.372276909
0.722769986
0.227700751
0.277008404
0.770084936
0.700850254
0.008503439
0.08503528
0.850353691
0.503537805
0.035378939
0.353790287
0.537903763
0.379038521
0.790386103
0.903861923
0.038620121
0.386202106
0.862021958
0.620220474
0.202205635
0.022057239
0.220573286
0.205733753
0.057338427
0.573385162
0.733852518
0.338526071
0.385261605
0.852616939
0.526170288
0.261703776
0.617038658
0.170387477
0.703875668
0.03875757
0.38757659
0.875766792
0.757668809
0.576688989
0.766890782
0.668908716
0.689088051
0.8908814
0.908814891
0.088149802
0.881498912
0.814990011
0.149901
0.499010891
0.9901098
0.901098889
0.010989787
0.109898766
0.098988551
0.989886401
0.898864907
0.988649962
0.886500517
0.865006065
```

I have 100 data from generating U(0,1) in Linear Congruential Generator.
In Random Variate Generator, I want to solve for Probability Density Function to Cummulative Distribution Function with Inverse Transformation.

This is the formula:
f(x) = 1/x^2 for 0 < x < 1 and f(x) = 0 for the other x

I need to find the inverse of f(x) to solve the random number generator LCG for U(0,1). The type of the distribution has a different formula.

Comment: It looks like you just gave a bar chart with each bar showing one value of a "random" number in the order they occurred. One can say very little from such a graph other than the values all seem to be in the interval $[0,1]$. A list of the actual numbers would be more informative; at least then people could make their own graphs. If the values were sorted from smallest to largest it might help a little bit.

Comment: @DavidK I edited and I put the actual data from generating in LCG.

Comment: Please do check the 'formula' you claim is a PDF. My answer assumes the support is $x > 1,$ so that it is the PDF of a Pareto distribution.
$Not\; 0 < x < 1.$

Comment: @BruceET What if the formula is 0 < x < 1? It would be a different distribution? Or it affect to the CDF?

Comment: There are many distributions with support $(0, 1).$ for example the entire family of beta distributions, but none of them are Pareto, and none of them have a PDF that is a multiple of $1/x^2.$

Comment: @BruceET How can you get this F−1(u) = 1/(1-u)? Can you give the details?

Comment: Let $u = F(x) = 1  - x^{-1}$ and solve for $x$ in terms of $u$, keeping track of possible values for $x$ and $u$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must mean that you're to use a distribution with the density function is $f(x) = x^{-2},$ for
$x > 1.$ This is a Pareto distribution. Then the cumulative
distribution function is $F(x) = 1 - x^{-1},$ for $x > 1.$
[Note: I do not believe your formula for $0 < x < 1$ is a proper
probability density function.]

For more on 'Pareto distributions',
see the Wikipedia article; in their terminology, yours has $\alpha=1$ and $x_m = 1.$ In addition, [this article](http://www.randomservices.org/random/special/Pareto.html) shows the CDF and quantile function
that I mention below (along with derivations).

You can use the 'inverse CDF' or 'quantile' function to generate
random observations from this Pareto distriution.
If $u = F(x) = 1 - x^{-1},$ then $x = F^{-1}(u) = 1/(1 - u),$
for $0 < u < 1$ is the quantile function.

One can show that if $U \sim Unif(0, 1)$ then
$X = 1/(1 - U)$ has your Pareto distribution. Thus, using each of
your 100 pseudorandom numbers as a realization of $U$, you should
be able to simulate a sample of size 100 from the Pareto distribution.

Using R software, I generated 100 observations from $Unif(0,1)$
and plotted them in the upper panel of the figure below. They
seem similar to the observations in your figure, which I believe
(along with @DavidK) are also uniformly distributed. The bottom panel shows the 100
corresponding Pareto random variables. This Pareto distribution
has a notoriously very heavy 'tail' towards high values; while many of the
Pareto values are small, occasional ones are quite large.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Comment: I put your list of pseudorandom numbers into a couple of
software packages. A 'runs' test finds them consistent with randomness.
a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test finds them consistent with $Unif(0,1).$

Some really awful LCG's could produce 100 observations that 'pass'
these tests and others. Vetting a pseudorandom generator of any
kind is a task for specialists, and 100 observations would not
be nearly enough output for powerful tests.

However, to answer
the specific question in title of your Question (at long last), it seems
reasonable to assume that the data you posted could be from
$Unif(0,1).$

The details of the K-S test in R are shown below. At least
this shows the data in a convenient format for R and other
packages, in case someone wants to investigate further.

```
 u = c(0.028048, 0.280481, 0.804808, 0.048083, 0.480832, 0.808323, 0.083234,
 0.832345, 0.323448, 0.234484, 0.344840, 0.448398, 0.483979, 0.839793,
 0.397935, 0.979351, 0.793514, 0.935144, 0.351437, 0.514374, 0.143737,
 0.437373, 0.373732, 0.737322, 0.373220, 0.732196, 0.321966, 0.219656,
 0.196561, 0.965613, 0.656129, 0.561292, 0.612922, 0.129219, 0.292192,
 0.921924, 0.219237, 0.192372, 0.923723, 0.237228, 0.372277, 0.722770,
 0.227701, 0.277008, 0.770085, 0.700850, 0.008503, 0.085035, 0.850354,
 0.503538, 0.035379, 0.353790, 0.537904, 0.379039, 0.790386, 0.903862,
 0.038620, 0.386202, 0.862022, 0.620220, 0.202206, 0.022057, 0.220573,
 0.205734, 0.057338, 0.573385, 0.733853, 0.338526, 0.385262, 0.852617,
 0.526170, 0.261704, 0.617039, 0.170387, 0.703876, 0.038758, 0.387577,
 0.875767, 0.757669, 0.576689, 0.766891, 0.668909, 0.689088, 0.890881,
 0.908815, 0.088150, 0.881499, 0.814990, 0.149901, 0.499011, 0.990110,
 0.901099, 0.010990, 0.109899, 0.098989, 0.989886, 0.898865, 0.988650,
 0.886501, 0.865006)

 ks.test(u, punif, 0, 1)

 ##        One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
 ##
 ## data:  u 
 ## D = 0.0628, p-value = 0.8256
 ## alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```